# Music briefly stops when i change from a video to images android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, android-music-player

I wrote an app that is designed to play background music while displaying varying images. I later added that every x number of pictures, by stopping my timer playing a video through VideoView and then after the video is completed, it returns to the images. However, when the video completes and it does change back to showing images, the music stops for 2 or 3 seconds before resuming. Any Ideas on what could cause this?

Here is my OnCompletion Code:

```
public void onVideoCompletion() {
        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.stopPlayback();
                VideoPlaying = false;
                videoView = null;
                if (VideoNo < myVideos.size())
                {
                    VideoNo++;
                }
                else {
                    VideoNo = 0;
                }
                StartPicTimer();
                imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```